# WSProxy to retrieve all data extension across all business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I have the following SSJS function which uses WSProxy to return an array of all data extensions across all business units, however, when I test the script in a CloudPage (in a child BU), it returns all data extensions **ONLY in the Parent BU**.

I'm hoping someone can take a look at the prox.retrieve() i put together and let me know why it's only retrieving Data Extensions in the Parent BU and not across all BUs even though I have QueryAllAccounts: true?

```
function pullAllDataExtensions() {
    var prox                            = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var moreData                        = true;
    var reqID                           = null;
    var cols                            = ["Name","CustomerKey","CategoryID","IsSendable", "Client.ID"];
    var filterAllDataExtensions         = {
                                            LeftOperand: {
                                                Property        : "IsSendable",
                                                SimpleOperator  : "equals",
                                                Value           : true
                                            },
                                            LogicalOperator: "OR",
                                            RightOperand: {
                                                Property        : "IsSendable",
                                                SimpleOperator  : "equals",
                                                Value           : false
                                            }
                                        }
    var options                         = {IncludeObjects: true};
    var props                           = { QueryAllAccounts: true };
    var dataExtensionResults            = [];
    while(moreData) {
        moreData = false;
        var data = reqID == null ?
            prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filterAllDataExtensions, options, props) : 
            prox.getNextBatch("DataExtension", reqID);
        if(data != null) {
            moreData    = data.HasMoreRows;
            reqID       = data.RequestID;
            if (data && data.Results) {
                for (i=0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                    dataExtensionResults.push(data.Results[i])
                }
            }
        }            
    };
    return dataExtensionResults
}
```

Comment: I have attempted and received same behavior on WSProxy, but it will function correctly via SOAP API. Perhaps this is a limitation of WSProxy that is just undocumented?

Comment: I have received confirmation that queryAllAccounts will only work from a top-down perspective. So to get all accounts, you will need to be at the parent level of your enterprise account.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm), the QueryAllAccounts is a true/false parameter instead of a JSON:

```
var queryAllAccounts = true;
[...YOUR CODE HERE...]
prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols, filter, options, queryAllAccounts );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i've tried that too and the results are the same

Comment: It also shows it as an object in the advanced retrieve section `var props = { QueryAllAccounts: true };`. Both will work correctly: (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_advanced_retrieve.htm)