# Pagination in SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, pagination

I need to fetch DataExtensions page-by-page but I didn't find anything useful for SOAP in SFMC

The only I found is how to [limit batch size for the response](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25099/72249)

Can I load the next batch, or is there another way to walk through pages?

Comment: check this. i dont think you have to bother with pagination.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/312601/wsproxy-to-retrieve-all-data-extension-across-all-business-units

Comment: I am only restricted to s2s credentials to the account, ssjs doesn't work in my case
But there are tricks with HasMoreRows and RequestID, will check it with SOAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination with the custom page size is possible by combining `ContinueRequest` and `BatchSize` properties

In example I paginate over `DataExtensionObjects` which have a useful auto-incremented identifier `_CustomObjectKey`

In the first request, we specify list of `Properties` and `BatchSize` which limits the number or entries in the response:

```xml
<RetrieveRequest>
    <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[SampleDataExtensionKey]</ObjectType>
    <Properties>_CustomObjectKey</Properties>
    <Properties>ColumnA</Properties>
    <Options>
        <BatchSize>10</BatchSize>
    </Options>
</RetrieveRequest>
```

In the response, we get the list of entries with indexes from 1 to 10

```xml
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>2f5db341-212a-47dd-a2f5-9ec41f2e8c5f</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>_CustomObjectKey</Name>
                <Value>1</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Results>
    ...
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>_CustomObjectKey</Name>
                <Value>10</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

When `MoreDataAvailable` is specified in the response we can take a `RequestID` which now refers to the stored request with `Properties`

Now we can request the next page with only specifying `RequestID` and `BatchSize`

`ObjectType` and `Properties` no more needed for further pagination. Actually, they are just ignored - you can not change properties between pagination steps

We can use different `BatchSize` on each iteration to increase or decrease the limit dynamically - it works consistently

```xml
<RetrieveRequest>
    <ContinueRequest>2f5db341-212a-47dd-a2f5-9ec41f2e8c5f</ContinueRequest>
    <Options>
        <BatchSize>12</BatchSize>
    </Options>
</RetrieveRequest>
```

Response:

```xml
<RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
    <RequestID>2f5db341-212a-47dd-a2f5-9ec41f2e8c5f</RequestID>
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>_CustomObjectKey</Name>
                <Value>11</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Results>
    ...
    <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
        <Properties>
            <Property>
                <Name>_CustomObjectKey</Name>
                <Value>22</Value>
            </Property>
        </Properties>
    </Results>
</RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

The `RequestID` returned for each page is always the same, it looks like it is stored statically and is not regenerated for every new response.
There is nothing in the documentation stating that it is always the same for the consequent requests, so I would recommend to always pick a returned one.

This also means that `ContinueRequest`s are not idempotent - every request changes the internal state of the `RequestID` - it holds (at least) the number of already returned objects, so you can not re-request the same page one more time.

Comment: And I have the exact problem with non-changing request ID. There's no way to get the 3rd (or any subsequent) page. `ContinueRequest` always returns the same 2nd page over and over again, even if there's `MoreDataAvailable` :/

Comment: Never mind.. We were using HTTP cache and because request never changed, we were getting same page all over from cache ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

When you make a [RetrieveRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieverequest.htm) where the response indicates there are further pages of results that may be retrieved, you'll receive an OverallStatus of "MoreDataAvailable" similar to this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:153f237f-aee1-4681-981d-73574e5d49ef</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:9f08a3e1-507a-4bb0-a955-66687ed0c2f6</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-a2156239-7103-4b72-bc7a-004c5d61224c">
                <wsu:Created>2020-09-30T01:21:11Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2020-09-30T01:26:11Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <OverallStatus>MoreDataAvailable</OverallStatus>
            <RequestID>b35a269a-eaf6-4d8c-9697-dae288d88531</RequestID>
            <Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
            ...
            </Results>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

To get the subsequent page, provide the RequestID from the previous response in the ContinueRequest property of the following RetrieveRequest:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <h:fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com" xmlns:h="http://exacttarget.com">{{_token}}</h:fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ContinueRequest>b35a269a-eaf6-4d8c-9697-dae288d88531</ContinueRequest>
                <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Contacts]</ObjectType>
                <Properties>uuid</Properties>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Sample PHP and DotNet code is provided in online documentation in [Retrieve More than 2500 Records Using the ContinueRequest Property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/continuerequest_2500records.htm).

Before going down the route of attempting to extract large amounts of data from Marketing Cloud Data Extensions, consider carefully using [Automation Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio.htm&type=5) and [Data Extension Extracts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_extension_extract.htm&type=5). This approach is far more scalable than using APIs for bulk extraction of data. Also keep in mind that, although not actively metered by Salesforce, you'll have a quota of API calls at your disposal that is finite and could become the object of Salesforce's monetization efforts in the future.